# inserting data from a form into your mysql database using php

Tags: php

i used this code

```
   <?php
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=CU4726629",'CU4726629','CU4726629'); 
    $sql="INSERT INTO review (username, movie_name, ratings) VALUES ("$_POST['username']","$_POST['moviename']","$_POST['ratings']")";

   header('Location: reviews.php');  
  ?>
```

but it keeps giving me this error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in
>   /home/4726629/public_html/check_login.php on line 5

Comment: You need to use either curly braces `{` `}` to enclose the variables, or concatenate them to the string. However it's not the proper usage of PDO, nor you are actually querying the db (it's just a string)

Answer (score 2):

Take this for an example:

```
 <?php
// insert some data using a prepared statement
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("insert into test (name, value) values (:name, :value)");
// bind php variables to the named placeholders in the query
// they are both strings that will not be more than 64 chars long
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name, PDO_PARAM_STR, 64);
$stmt->bindParam(':value', $value, PDO_PARAM_STR, 64);
// insert a record
$name = 'Foo';
$value = 'Bar';
$stmt->execute();
// and another
$name = 'Fu';
$value = 'Ba';
$stmt->execute();
// more if you like, but we're done
$stmt = null;
?>
```

You just wrote a string in your above code:

```
    $sql="INSERT INTO review (username, movie_name, ratings) VALUES ("$_POST['username']","$_POST['moviename']","$_POST['ratings']")";
```

Comment: Put his string in the example, so one can learn how to bind $_POST vars :) Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Above answers are correct, you will need to concat the strings to form a valid sql query. you can echo your $sql variable to check what is to be executed and if is valid sql query or not. you might want to look in to escaping variables you will be using in your sql queries else your app will be vulnerable to sql injections attacks.

look in to

[http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php)

http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Also you will need to query you prepared sql statement.

look in to http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php

Answer (score 1):

A couple of errors:

1) you have to concat the strings!
like this:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO review (username, movie_name, ratings) 
                 VALUES (".$_POST['username'].",".$_POST['moviename'].",".$_POST['ratings'].")";
```

2) you are not using the PDO at all:
after you create the "insert" string you must query the db itself, something like using

```
$conn->query($sql);
```

nb: it is pseudocode

3) the main problem is that this approach is wrong.
constructing the queries in this way lead to many security problems.
Eg: what if I put "moviename" as "; drop table review;" ??? It will destroy your db.
So my advice is to use [prepared statement](http://www.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements):

```
$sql="INSERT INTO review (username, movie_name, ratings) 
                 VALUES (?,?,?)";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$fill_array = array($_POST['username'], $_POST['moviename'], $_POST['ratings']);
$q->execute($fill_array);
```

Answer (score -1):

You forgot dots:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO review (username, movie_name, ratings) 
                 VALUES (".$_POST['username'].",".$_POST['moviename'].",".$_POST['ratings'].")";
```

and fot the future for now your variables are not escaped so code is not secure

Comment: His SQL query is not executed, so the secure problems won't fire. However, if it was executed, whichever MySQL api using, this querystring will not work because of column types